# Is there a blend mode to replace black and keep other colors (i.e. white)?

Tags: svg, flutter, graphics

I want to create a dynamically colored map marker in flutter_svg

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?><!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg style="fill-rule:evenodd;clip-rule:evenodd;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-miterlimit:1.41421;" height="100%" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="100%"  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  xml:space="preserve">
    <g transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,4,0)">
    <path style="fill:rgb(0,0,0);" d="M8.25,0C3.689,0 0,3.756 0,8.4C0,14.7 8.25,24 8.25,24C8.25,24 16.5,14.7 16.5,8.4C16.5,3.756 12.811,0 8.25,0Z"/>
    <path style="fill:rgb(255,255,255);" d="M8.25,11.4C6.624,11.4 5.304,10.056 5.304,8.4C5.304,6.744 6.624,5.4 8.25,5.4C9.876,5.4 11.196,6.744 11.196,8.4C11.196,10.056 9.876,11.4 8.25,11.4Z"/>
    </g>
</svg>
```

which looks like this:

[image: Marker]

I am experimenting with [Blend Modes](https://github.com/flutter/engine/blob/master/lib/ui/painting.dart#L376).

If I use this:

```
SvgPicture.asset(
      "assets/images/to_marker.svg",
      package: "trufi_core",
      color: const Color(0xff27ae60),
      colorBlendMode: BlendMode.difference,
    )
```

the white color becomes transparent:

[image: result]

Is there even a blend mode which just replaces black by the color, and leaves white intact or do I have to use some color replacing?

Is there another way to replace a color in flutter_svg, maybe with CSS?

Answer (score 2):

By brute forcing (trying all the modes) I found out, that `BlendMode.screen` works for this case

Comment: `BlendMode.screen` makes transparent pixels opaque for this icon in flutter_svg: 0.22.0. 
Do you have a different result?